# How to set up Loopback Angular SDK on separate server from Loopback Backend

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

Title says it all.

Loopback is on a server, and I'm building a front-end on a different server. The docs for Loopback Angular SDK specifically say you have to link it to the loopback server.js. That is not available to me. What is available to me is the JSON from the loopback models.

Is there a way I can make loopback angular work with those JSON models and not need the server.js? Or are the two just impossible to separate (loopback angular and loopback itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. [Loopback supports CORS by default](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Security+considerations#Securityconsiderations-CORS), but you also have to configure Angular for it:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myAppApiService']);

myApp.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

Additionally, keep in mind that [CORS is not 100% supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) in IE8 and 9.